# sqlite3 binding first project

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm doing my first project in sqlite3 using python . But I keep getting an error saying:

> MCurs.execute("""UPDATE Artist SET
> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 5.

```
MCurs.execute("""UPDATE Artist SET
    first_name=:first,
    last_name=:last,
    genre=:genre,
    album=:album
    
    Where oid =:oid""",
    {
    'first':first_name_box_edit.get(),
    'last':last_name_box_edit.get(),
    'genre':genre_box_edit.get(),
    'album':album_box_edit.get()
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your error was that you said `:oid` but gave no assignment for `:oid` in the dictionary. So you will have to specify what the `:oid` is in the dictionary, like:

```
{
    'first':first_name_box_edit.get(),
    'last':last_name_box_edit.get(),
    'genre':genre_box_edit.get(),
    'album':album_box_edit.get(),
    'oid':whatever_variable #here you have to specify your oid
}
```

Or there is this better way of using placeholders with SQLite, ie, `?`. Here is how:

```
sql_command = """UPDATE Artist SET
    first_name=?,
    last_name=?,
    genre=?,
    album=?
    Where oid=?"""
values = first_name_box_edit.get(),last_name_box_edit.get(),genre_box_edit.get(),album_box_edit.get(),oid_variable)
MCurs.execute(sql_command,values)
```

Basically your just changing `:first` with `?` and then later giving a value for that from the passed tuple. Here `values` is the tuple. Though you can combine all these into just a single `execute()`. Also keep in mind whatever value your passing **HAS** to be a tuple.

**But either way keep in mind, your not passing in the value for `oid` and that is the error.**

Answer (score 0):

oid is miss, look this way, that is more correct and simple, I've "supply a value for binding 5" that is oid = 1

```
sql = "UPDATE Artist  SET first_name =?, last_name =?,  genre =?, album =? WHERE oid =?"

args = (first_name_box_edit.get(),
        last_name_box_edit.get(),
        genre_box_edit.get(),
        album_box_edit.get(),
        1)

cur.execute(sql, args)
```